# Join 2 tables on multiple case conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using pgAdmin on a Postgres db. I am trying to achieve the following result (amounts are random):

[image: result_table]

In order to do that, I need to query the 2 tables: accounts and transactions

[image: accounts]

[image: transactions]

I am not sure how to get the sum(amount) results into 1 column. I have tried the following:

```
select SUM(
    CASE WHEN debit_account_id = 1 then amount
        when credit_account_id = 1 then amount * (-1) else 0 end),
        SUM(
    CASE WHEN debit_account_id = 2 then amount
        when credit_account_id = 2 then amount * (-1) else 0 end)
    from transactions
    where entity_id = 1
```

and so on up to account_id 6. This will give me the correct sums for each account but each result is in new column. How I can combine this so the results looks like in example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL`.

```
select debit_account_id account_id, -amount from transactions
union all 
select credit_account_id account_id, amount from transactions;
```

now you have data together in one column

Comment: yes that is actually the simplest way, my god, thanks!

Comment: @Lukas: If an answer solved the problem you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd sum the debits and the credits for each account in different queries and join them on the accounts table:

```
SELECT account_name, sum_credut - sum_debit AS balance
FROM   accounts a
JOIN   (SELECT   credit_account_id, SUM(amount)
        FROM     transfer
        GROUP BY credit_account_id) c ON a.id = c.credit_account_id
JOIN  (SELECT    debit_account_id, SUM(amount)
        FROM     transfer
        GROUP BY debit_account_id) d ON a.id = d.debit_account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a lateral joins for this:

```
select a.account_name,
       sum(v.signed_amount) as total_amount
from transactions t left join lateral
     (values (t.debit_account_id, t.amount), 
             (t.credit_account_id, - t.amount)
     ) v(account_id, signed_amount) join
     account a
     on a.id = v.account_id
group by a.account_name;
```

I don't see `entity_id` in any of the tables, so I don't know where that comes from.